# Cordova hosted web app - open input type=file in camera

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

Im working on a cordova web app project. I'm having problem to open camera when I click on the file input. This is what I tried so far by adding media capture attributes:

Cordova - index.js

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
        window.location.href = "https://www.example.com/webapp/";
}
```

Hosted Website - add_picture.php

```
<input type="file" name="image" id="image" accept="image/*" capture />
```

It's not working even with the extra tag inside input element. It opens my phone's file manager instead. Is there any way to solve this and open my camera when I click on the input? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do this with straight HTML5, then there's no way to open the camera directly with one press, you'll still have a Library or Camera dialog to choose from.

There's another way to do this with the Cordova plugin, "Camera"; but it becomes a lot more difficult with hosted web apps as your hosted web app cannot directly communicate with your plugins. It's not impossible though. Use the below references to help with this task, if you're inclined.

- https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-hostedwebapp

Comment: You mean to inject cordova camera plugin into the website by using plugin-hostedwebapp?